# Hacer crecer una fila en el detalle de reporte de crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Tengo el siguiente reporte:

[image: Reporte Crystal]

Pero en una columna un valor se trunca visualmente, quisiera de ser posible que la fila creciera a lo alto para poder mostrar todo el texto posible.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Los campos crecen de acuerdo al espacio asignado, en tu caso el campo asignado no tiene crecimiento por lineas si no que por espacio(Ancho y largo) se puede visualizar eso en **Click derecho, Tamaño y posición**.

Lo que necesitas seria, si ya tienes identificado el tamaño de la variable que pones puede ser que ocupe 100,150 o mas caracteres, darle click derecho al campo y elegir la opción **Dar formato al texto**.

[image: Campo a seleccionar]

Luego de eso en la pestaña **Común** has los siguientes cambios: cambiar la casilla **Puede crecer** y utilizar el numero de lineas que desees que rellene.

[image: Selección de casilla puede crecer y numero de lineas]

Este cambio ayuda a dicho campo a crecer de acuerdo a la carag de caracteres que vaya a recibir, por eso anteriormente te mencione lo de identificar el tamaño del campo en base de datos para calcular las lineas necesarias que ocupara en caso se ocupe el máximo de caracteres de dicho campo.

Saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente, es la respuesta correcta, lo había intentado pero sin éxito. Ya que en mi caso al ser un reporte de SAP B1 el archivo que se edita es un archivo "temporal" el cual después de realizar el ajuste recomendado, se debe guardar en alguna ubicacion y posteriormente desde SAP volverlo a "importar" para que el cambio surta efecto.